# How can we make it easier to handle or reduce the frequent merge conflicts in message files in an Angular app?

Tags: angular, internationalization, devops, workflow

When Developer A merges their branch into the main/feature branch and makes modifications to i18n texts, Developer 2 often faces the need to resolve merge conflicts during the merge of their branch into the main/feature branch. This typically occurs in message files, which can become quite lengthy and encounter numerous conflicts due to line alterations and the addition of new translations. These conflicts make it challenging to merge message files without losing translated content.

Our objective is to simplify testing for specific tasks that involve translated texts in separate branches. We aim to alleviate the burden of managing message files in Angular, relying on human translators to handle the translations. The translated files will then be automatically generated within our Jenkins pipeline, reducing the occurrence of merge conflicts. While we currently use the https://angular.io/guide/i18n-overview tool, we are open to exploring alternative i18n solutions.